# Groupby or Looping for conditional replacing

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

Am relatively new to Python.
I have a dataframe of the below nature

```
ID     DEPT     DOMAIN          
201606  271     GE
**201606  896     IR**
201608  271     GE
201609  271     GE
.....................            
...................           
**201701  896     FR**
201606  271     GE
```

I want to find all the Departments who have seen a change in their domain names starting 2017 in the ID.
And then, I would like to replace the Domain (in the 2016* rows) with the value of the Domain that matches the book value of 2017* rows
For eg, in the above illustrated df, i would like to replace the Domain value of 2016* rows for DEPT 896 with FR, which is the domain value of the corresponding Dept from 2017* rows.

Comment: can you share what you have tried

Comment: I was initially trying to get a mapping of the Dept and Domain.
And hence tried using groupby or drop_duplicates method to understand the mapping.
However there are quite a few Depts and hence not easy to visualize a picture.
The next thing that is being tried is:
For each row iteration, for each Dept,  update the previous rows with the latest occuring(in the dataset or 2017* onwards) value for Domain

Comment: @asimo - `2017` is max year? Or there is also 2018 ?

Comment: 2017 is max year

Comment: @asimo - thanks, so my solution working nice.

Comment: Mine too.... ;)

Answer (score 2):

I think you need first [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) and then use [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) for Series by `last 2017` and last `map` + `fillna`:

```
m1 = ~df.sort_values('ID').duplicated('DEPT', keep='last')
m2 = df['ID'].astype(str).str[:4] == '2017'
s = df[m1 & m2].set_index('DEPT')['DOMAIN']
df['DOMAIN'] = df['DEPT'].map(s).fillna(df['DOMAIN'])

print (df)
       ID  DEPT DOMAIN
0  201606   271     GE
1  201606   896     FR
2  201608   271     GE
3  201609   271     GE
4  201701   896     FR
5  201606   271     GE
```

Comment: I do encounter ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis on the s = df[m1 & m2].set_index('DEPT')['DOMAIN'] operation. Its perhaps due to there being multiple DOMAINS for a given DEPT. May be I'll have to replace or handle all these multiple domains for a given DEPT in a different way

Comment: I am confused. Because `.duplicated('DEPT', keep='last')` always return only one unique `DEPT` - remove all duplicates and return only last. So I dont understand how is possible you get multiple values. Are data confidental?

Comment: It is..
For the time being, stakeholders seem only interested in getting one specifc domain changed..
So i have used np.where to replace that one.. 
df['Domain'] = np.where(df['ID'] < 201701, 
                                  np.where(df['Domain'] == 'IR', 'FR', df['Domain']), 
                                  df['Domain'])
ID has been cast as int..
I'll revisit the duplicate issue soon..for a possible permanent solution..
Cheers!!

Comment: Thanks for explanation, then is possible simplify code to `df['Domain'] = df['Domain'].mask((df['ID'] < 201701) & (df['Domain'] == 'IR'), 'FR')`